# VSCode warning in RPG-LE ("Subroutines should not be defined in the global scope")

Tags: vscode-extensions, rpgle

When I write free rpg code in VS Code (with the usual extensions for IBM i), I get a warning that subroutines should not be declared in the global scope.

I want to keep working with subroutines, only using procedures when needed.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid such a warning in a full free RPG, you can do this:

```
ctl-opt main(Main);

...

dcl-proc Main;
  dcl-pi *n;
    ...
  end-pi;

  ...

  return;

  begsr ...;
    ...
  endsr;
end-proc;
```

This way you can use subroutines inside Main (as well as inside any other procedure) and they won't be in the global scoupe

Comment: Maybe it is useful: https://devcodef1.com/news/1143973/vscode-warning-free-rpg-code-subroutines

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It took care of the VSCode message. Follow up question is, is this common procedure ? I mean to ask is this the way a program should be written, in one main procedure ?

Comment: Yes, this is a common procedure. You can write your entire program inside it (a program consisting of one single procedure).
And you can call it whatever you like (unlike C where the main procedure should always be called 'main'). It becomes the main one after the announcement ctl-opt main(Main) (which indicates the entry point of your program). Everything (variables, templates, constants) that is declared outside of it will have a global scoupe. Everything declared inside has a local scoupe for this procedure (including subroutines)

Answer (score 0):

All,

sorry as I may have posted this question prematurely. I found the answer to my own question, and maybe this will help others.

The solution is alter a line in the lint code:

```
{
  "indent": 2,
  "PrototypeCheck": true,
  "NoOCCURS": true,
  "NoSELECTAll": true,
  "UppercaseConstants": true,
  "IncorrectVariableCase": true,
  "NoSQLJoins": true,
  "PrettyComments": true,
  **"NoGlobalSubroutines": false**,
  "NoExternalTo": [
    "QCMD",
    "QP2TERM",
    "QSH",
    "SYSTEM",
    "QCMDEXC"
  ]
}
```

I did restart VSCode to make sure it was active.

Comment: Modern RPGLE is a procedural language and the program runs in linear mode and not in cycle mode as in the “old” RPG.
And this warning is inserted into VSCode for a reason, but to ensure that the developer uses a more “correct” approach with minimal use of global scoupe, which provides more structured code.